# How can I use Python files in web page for crud operations on database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, python-2.7

Someone tell me that what kind of changes I in my computer or file have to do for running py files in web page by xampp server, I have a simple code of getting data from database and it is also working properly, it is giving me tuple in list and no error is there while running it with cmd or vs code terminal

```
#! C:/Users/ashok/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32
print("Content-Type:text/html")
import mysql.connector

print('<h1>Welcome to the Python</h1>')

conn= mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', username='root', password='', database='first_db_py')
cur = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM test"
cur.execute(query)

print(cur.fetchall())

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

if you are able to understand this code so please tell me because I have watched so many tutorials on youtube but I didn't get

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please improve your answer and clarify your exact question.